# How access the original observed node by MutationObserver when subtree is true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom, mutation-observers

How can I access the original target `node` when using `MutationObserver` with options `childList` and `subtree` set to `true`?

On the callbacks, the target is changed to whatever node has mutated, and this is expected as per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but my intention is to always be able to look at the original node, so I can evaluate if it is overflowing.

Why is this my intention?

Well, it's because I have noticed that, depending on the edge case, the `ResizeObserver` won't trigger, while the `MutationObserver` with the configs as per stated above, will trigger. Therefore I would like to access the original node in this scenario so I can calculate if it is overflowing.

So I do not care about what exactly is going on inside the subtree. I just want to use this callback to access the original node and evaluate if it is overflowing.

```
export const setupObserver = ({
  observer,
  callback, 
  node,
}) => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  
  // I want to somehow access the original node always when the callback is executed
  observer.observe(node, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
}
```

Of course, if I know how to find the original node inside the callback function, it works fine. But it would cause a dependency, which is something I would like to avoid.

For example:

```
const callbackFunction = useCallback(
    (records: MutationRecord[]) => {

// ignore the internals of this function.
// the point is that getting by ID works inside the callback
// allowing me to calculate if it is overflowing or not
// but this would cause a dependency, which I would like to avoid
        checkOverflow({
          element: document.getElementById('overflowing-test'),
          state: isOverflow,
          setState: setIsOverflow,
        });
    }
    , [isOverflow],
  );
```

Comment: the `observe` methos allows you pass these 2 options as true: `attributeOldValue` and `characterDataOldValue`, maybe that's what you're looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe

Comment: I do not think so. I want to access the ```node``` element passed as the first argument. The problem is that the ```target``` returned inside the callbacks in this case may be deeply nested down. I guess that the old value will not give me the updated original observed node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by binding the node to callback when creating the observer:

```
export const setupObserver = ({
  observer,
  callback, 
  node,
}) => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback.bind(null, node));
  ...
```

Then access it as first callback argument:

```
const callbackFunction =
    (node: HTMLElement, records: MutationRecord[]) => {
```

Comment: great! Thanks for sharing this. As I use `useCallback` with the current state as a dependency, I will get the updated node every time this callback function is executed, therefore getting the updated node! Great! This made me rethink the whole approach of the hook itself!